# How to order_by in MY_Model(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, my-model-jami

I have integrated the Jamie Rumbelow My Model for doing active record queries with codeigniter from github - [https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model]

```
//SELECT * FROM `product_pricings` where vendor_id=1 order by  price desc ;

$data['product_priceAsc']=$this->Product_pricing_model->get_many_by(array('vendor_id' =>$vendor_id))->order_by($price);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['product_priceAsc']);exit;
```

I have tried this in many ways like mentioned in the MY_Model. I'm Newbie for My_model and i struck here.

1. I have given the `SQL` code which i tried to get in the Controller.
2. The second one is what i have tried to do that in controller. the Problem is how to pass order_by -> the `table` price `ASC`.
   A little help will be Appreciated .

Comment: In PHP never c/p code that is 3-4 years old. Check [Avenirer's](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) one that is maintained on regular basis, but also pretty much well documented.

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, why are you using a custom model for things that are supported out of the box by the Active Record helper? =/

Comment: I really dont get you clearly Dave